# Socket.io possible emitter issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, game-development

I have recently started getting into socket.io. Learning by implementing a multiplayer game on React with Redux and TS.

Here's a video of the strange issue I notice in redux devtools. I am not sure if this is an issue with Redux or Socket.io. What you're about to see is an action being fired in an interval, that changes the `players` array. The action doesn't affect in any way the `player` *(notice singular)* object.

Is this an issue with Socket.io or you'd suspect something wrong with Redux devtools or also likely something a rookie socket.io developer (me) did wrong?

[image: Redux devtools in two tabs]

**Server**

```
// server.js

const io = require('socket.io')();

/**
 * When a player joins
 */
const SUBSCRIBE_PLAYER = "subscribePlayer";
const DISCONNECT = "disconnect";
/**
 * Current players, etc
 */
const SERVER_STATE = "state";

/**
 * Initial state
 */
const players = {};
let playerScore = 0;

/**
 * Handle socket connections incomming from client
 */
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on(SUBSCRIBE_PLAYER, (data) => {
    console.log("+++++++++++++")
    console.log(`ID: ${data.id}`)
    console.log(`NAME: ${data.name}`)
    console.log(`SCORE: ${data.score}`)
    console.log("+++++++++++++")

    /**
     * Check if unique player
     */
    players[data.id] = {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      score: data.score,
    }
  });

  socket.emit(SUBSCRIBE_PLAYER, { id: socket.id, name: "",  score: playerScore });

  /**
   * Remove player on disconnect
   */
  socket.on(DISCONNECT, (reason) => {   
    delete players[socket.id];
  });
});

/**
 * Notify client about server state
 */
setInterval(() => {
  io.sockets.emit(SERVER_STATE, players);
}, 1000);

const port = 8000;
io.listen(port);
console.log('Client listening on port ' + port);
```

**Client**

```
// This is being emitted in the above server.js in an interval
export function listenGameState(dispatch: Dispatch<any>) {
    socket.on(SERVER_STATE, (players: Players) => {
        // Plain action. Not a thunk
        dispatch(addPlayersAction(players)); // modifies only players object in the state
    });
}


// Reducer
export function commonReducer(state = initialState, action: ReducerActions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_PLAYER: {
            return {
                ...state,
                player: {
                    id: action.payload.id,
                    name: action.payload.name,
                    score: action.payload.score,
                },
            };
        }
        case ADD_PLAYERS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                players: action.payload,
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Ended up not doing anything about this. Seems to work fine. However, if anyone knows the issue, please don't hesitate to post an answer. :)

Happy coding!

Comment: Can you give more clarity on the code?
What do you mean by changing the array? (sequence of items vs new items)
Where the change is ? (in the redux store vs the socket payload)

Comment: 1) Sorry, not changing players array, but object. Returning a new `players` state object after every `io.sockets.emit(SERVER_STATE, players);` 

2) `listenGameState` listens to the event and dispatches the action that in turn creates a new redux state. Have I answered your questions?

Comment: I suspect it is a weird behavior of how `dev-tools`. To confirm that, you can check the previous state to current state value in a shallow mode.

Comment: I put my money on dev tools as well. Because the action and diff tabs don’t show the data that you can see in the gif. In fact they show correct data in the diff and correct action being dispatched